# Construct a subclass based on its constructor arguments?

Tags: java, constructor

If I have an abstract class and its subclasses:

```
public abstract class Animal{
  //other methods..
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
  private int legs;
  public Dog(int legs){
      this.legs = legs;
  }
}

public class Fish extends Animal{
  private int legs;
  private int speed;

  public Fish(int legs, int speed){
      this.legs = legs;
      this.speed = speed;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to initalize a new Dog or Fish by simply using constructor overloading?

Something like:

```
public void createNewAnimal(int new_legs, int new_speed){
  new Animal(new_legs, new_speed) //Makes fish.
  new Animal(new_legs) //Makes dog.
}
```

Comment: By definition of "abstract class", no.

Comment: Even if it weren't abstract, given that `new SomeClass` always creates an instance of (exactly) `SomeClass`, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor is part of its class, so you can't overload it to create different classes. You could, however, have a factory with overloaded methods:

```
public class AnimalFactory {
    public static Animal create(int legs, int speed) {
        return new Fish(legs, speed);
    }

    public static Animal create(int speed) {
        return new Dog(speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for a factory method instead.  You want to have a method create a new object for different parameters.

```
public static Fish makeFish(int newLegs, int newSpeed) {
    return new Fish(newLegs, newSpeed);
}

public static Dog makeDog(int newLegs) {
    return new Dog(newLegs);
}
```